# Javascript JQuery first time user trying to place form below picture with certain url

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, forms

Hi I'm trying to place a form below an image with a certain URL, however it's not working. I'm not exactly sure 
what I'm doing wrong since I'm new to JQuery. Would anyone happen to know what's wrong with this?

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript">
function main(){
    var imageURL = getImageURL();
    $("img[src=imageURL]");
    $("img[src='Your URL']").append("<input type="radio" name="geo" value="geolocation">Use Geolocation? <br> Additional Information About the Image: <input type="comment" name="cmnt">");

}

function getImageURL(){
var url = "http://www.w3schools.com/images/pulpit.jpg";
return url;
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="main()">
<b> Page </b>
<img src="http://www.w3schools.com/images/pulpit.jpg">

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of problems.  You can't use the variable `imageURL` can't be placed directly inside the src selector. You need to concatenate it in with `+`.  Then, rather than [`.append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/) which adds to a given node's *child nodes* you need to use [`.after()`](http://api.jquery.com/after/) to add elements as sibling nodes to the selector.

Rather than just a single `<input>` you should be appending a `<form>` with the `<input>` nested inside it.

```
function main(){
    var imageURL = getImageURL();
    // Concatenate the imageURL variable into the $() selector.
    // Put the <input> inside a <form> if it needs to function as a form element.
    $("img[src='" + imageURL + "']").after("<form><input type="radio" name="geo" value="geolocation">Use Geolocation? <br> Additional Information About the Image: <input type="comment" name="cmnt"></form>");

}
```

Answer (score 2):

The jQuery method `.append()` actually adds its argument INSIDE the given node. Instead, use [after()](http://api.jquery.com/after/) method, which inserts content AFTER the specified element.

Answer (score 1):

Along with the first answer, there are a few other things:

Your JQuery Library needs http:// in front of it.

Your String is encapsulated in Double quotes and contains double quotes, you need to escape the inner double quotes or just encapsulate the string in single quotes.

Comment: The `//` is called a _protocol relative URL_. It will use https if the page is https, or http if the page is http. You don't have to specify the protocol.

Comment: It was causing failure on my end when testing it locally.. I'll look in to why.. Thanks.